# Multicolumn text centering

Tags: tables

This is my code to create a table:

```
\begin{table*}
\caption{Test and Out of sample results}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}

  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ABCDE 1}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ABCDE 2}} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}

  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 77  & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline
  AX & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &  & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
  AY & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &  & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}


\label{acc_results}
\end{table*}
```

Result:

[image]

I want `ABCDE 2` in middle like `ABCDE`. How can I do this?

Comment: I know that you have already accepted an answer but you should accept the _best_ answer. (Just saying. `:-)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, even though Andrew has already [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236791/15874)ed your question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition = top]{caption}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \caption{Test and Out of sample results.}
 \label{acc_results}
  \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
   \toprule
       & \mc{ABCDE~1}       &    & \mc{ABCDE~2}        \\
         \cmidrule(lr){2-5}        \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5      & 77 & 6 & 7 & 8 &  9      \\
   \midrule
    AX & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5      &    & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10      \\
    AY & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5      &    & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10      \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that `\label` has to come after `\caption` in table environments, so you have done nothing wrong, but it's easier to read the code (I think) if you put them together.

A few suggestions:

- Use the [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to get a better thickness of -- and spacing around -- the horizontal rules.
- Use the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the option `tableposition = top` to get better spacing between the caption and the table.
- Use the syntax `*{<number of columns>}{c}` to shorten the code, since all the columns are centered.
- Structure the input code to make it look like the output to get a better overview of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `&` in the `\multicolumn` row:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \caption{Test and Out of sample results}
  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}

    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ABCDE 1}} && \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ABCDE 2}} \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}

    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 77  & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
    AX & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &  & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
    AY & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &  & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \label{acc_results}
  \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]